# vector gets overwritten by push_back funtion

Tags: c++, vector

This is my first question here so tolerate my mistakes. I am writing homework about a race. I need the 2D vector to store position of the racers, and where it's empty it's going to be `null`. I ran into the following problem. Through a lot of `cout`'s I discovered that the `push_back` function overwrites the whole vector every time. I know this question has been asked, but I can't find a solution to this anywhere.

`Race` is the class, and the problematic function is `add_contestant`.

```
class Race{
    public:
    int x;

    Race(int x){
        this->x = x;
    }

    vector< vector<Racer*> > contestants;

    void add_contestant(Racer &moi_chovek){

        vector<Racer*> guy_to_add;
        guy_to_add.push_back(&moi_chovek);
        contestants.push_back(guy_to_add);

        int index = contestants.size() - 1;
        int i;
        Racer *r;   
        r->name = "0";
        for(i=1; i<x; i++){
            contestants[index].push_back(r);    
        }
    }

    void print_all_contestants_names(){
        int i=0,j=0;
        for(i=0; i<contestants.size(); i++){
            for(j=0; j<contestants[i].size(); j++){
                cout<<contestants[i][j]->name<<" ";
            }
            cout<<"\n";
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `Racer *r; r->name = "0";` is absolutely wrong and invokes *undefined behavior*. `r` does not point at a valid `Racer` object

Comment: Which `push_back`?

Comment: for(i=1; i<x; i++){
            contestants[index].push_back(r);    
        }

Comment: the one in the for loop

Comment: As soon as you did something that causes undefined behavior you cannot expect that anything after that point will produce correct results. You therefore first have to fix `Racer *r; r->name = "0";`

Comment: Well ok, but then how do i fill up the vector to the Xth element, without creating such object?

Comment: `Racer *r;` does not create a `Race` object it is just a pointer that can point to an instance of `Race` (e.g. instances create by `new Race`). You probably should revisit the slides to your course that explains how instances of classes are created, and what pointers are.

Comment: Pushing `Racer &moi_chovek` to `guy_to_add` and pushing that to `contestants.push_back` would only be valid if it is guaranteed if the lifetime of the object that is passed to `add_contestant` is longer then the one of the instance of `Race`.

Answer (score 0):

At first i don't get the idea of makeing 2d vector while u only add 1 value ! but lets keep with ur code :
Here u didn't init the object so the pointer is pointing to somewhere else not that address of the object u trying to modfiy

```
r->name = "0";
```

...

```
contestants[index].push_back(r);
```

Here u add to every 1d values the r pointer , it makes no sense ! you have to access to the racer from contestants and use function to set the name value , something will look like this :

```
    for(i=0; i<contestants.size(); i++){
        for(j=0; j<contestants[i].size(); j++){
            contestants[i][j]->setName("0");
        }
    }
```

Comment: A point will always point somewhere. It just might not be valid to dereference it because it is not pointing to an instance of `Racer`. The uninitialized `r` does not necessarily need to hold the same value on each call of `add_contestant`, the `r` pushed to  `push_back` could be different each time (but that's not relevant as it has to be assumed to be invalid anyway). The phrasing `Here u overwrite every 1d values with this […]` is misleading, `push_back` does not overwrite, it appends elements to the vector stored in `contestants[index]`

Comment: @t.niese
Oh thats my bad  you're right, i will edit my answer ,